# Alphanumeric Sorting in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

can anyone help me how to sort this? 
I have a dynamical list of pattern that I want to sort, it contains alphanumeric value and letters.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Pattern (Pattern varchar(50) NULL)
INSERT INTO dbo.Pattern (Pattern) VALUES ('A11')
INSERT INTO dbo.Pattern (Pattern) VALUES ('A12')
INSERT INTO dbo.Pattern (Pattern) VALUES ('A8')
INSERT INTO dbo.Pattern (Pattern) VALUES ('A2')
INSERT INTO dbo.Pattern (Pattern) VALUES ('B6')
INSERT INTO dbo.Pattern (Pattern) VALUES ('B21')
INSERT INTO dbo.Pattern (Pattern) VALUES ('B10')
INSERT INTO dbo.Pattern (Pattern) VALUES ('B3')
INSERT INTO dbo.Pattern (Pattern) VALUES ('B100')
INSERT INTO dbo.Pattern (Pattern) VALUES ('B2')
INSERT INTO dbo.Pattern (Pattern) VALUES ('AA')
INSERT INTO dbo.Pattern (Pattern) VALUES ('BA')
INSERT INTO dbo.Pattern (Pattern) VALUES ('A20')
INSERT INTO dbo.Pattern (Pattern) VALUES ('AB')
INSERT INTO dbo.Pattern (Pattern) VALUES ('BB')

SELECT Pattern FROM dbo.Pattern ORDER BY Pattern

DROP Table dbo.Pattern
```

The result shows like this:

```
 A11
 A12
 A2
 A20
 A8
 AA
 AB
 B10
 B100
 B2
 B21
 B3
 B6
 BA
 BB
```

But All I want to show is like this result:

```
AA
A1
A2
A8
A11
A12
A20
AB
BA
B2
B3
B6
B10
B21
B100
BB
```

Comment: plus 1 for sample data

Comment: Can you define the logic behind your desired result?   Why does `AA` come after `B100`?   Which would come first between `AAA` and `BA1`?  Why?   If you could define the logic, I bet you'd be able to answer your own question easily.

Comment: @TabAlleman, I already edit the content of the result that should be output for pattern sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Pattern
FROM dbo.Pattern 
ORDER BY LEFT(Pattern,1), 
        CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Pattern,2,LEN(Pattern)) LIKE '%[0-9]%' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(Pattern,2,LEN(Pattern)) as int) 
            WHEN SUBSTRING(Pattern,2,LEN(Pattern)) = 'A' THEN 0
            ELSE 10000000 END,
            SUBSTRING(Pattern,2,LEN(Pattern))
```

Will output:

```
Pattern
AA
A2
A8
A11
A12
A20
AB
BA
B2
B3
B6
B10
B21
B100
BB
```

Answer (score 1):

For your sample data, this comes close:

```
order by left(pattern, patindex('%[0-9]%', pattern)),
         patindex('%[0-9]%', pattern),
         len(pattern) asc,
         pattern
```

But, you want the all alphas to be last, so a `case` is needed (I think):

```
order by left(pattern, patindex('%[0-9]%', pattern)),
         (case when pattern like '%[0-9]%'
               then patindex('%[0-9]%', pattern)
               else 999
          end),
         len(pattern) asc,
         pattern
```

Comment: It's not returning output as asked above. why ?

Comment: Well this logic would mean that `B1` would come before `A10` because it has a shorter length.

Comment: @Suraz . . . You already have the answer, but I fixed this answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Pattern
FROM dbo.Pattern
ORDER BY CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Pattern) > 0
              THEN LEFT(Pattern, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Pattern)-1)
              ELSE Pattern
         END,
         CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Pattern) > 0
              THEN CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(Pattern, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Pattern), LEN(Pattern)))
              ELSE 0
         END
```

Please search the net and Stack Overflow before posting.

**Reference:** http://www.essentialsql.com/use-sql-server-to-sort-alphanumeric-values/

Comment: It returns `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.` error. Throw error for the values of `AA`, `BA`, since  those doesn't have numeric value, so `LEFT('AA', 0 - 1)` throw error.

Comment: Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: @ayakamacy I updated my answer to use a `CASE` expression to handle patterns which contain only letters.

Comment: @Arulkumar I updated my answer sir, kindly have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I would separater alpha and num parts:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Pattern)=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,--Put no-nums last
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Pattern) != 0 THEN LEFT(Pattern, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Pattern)-1) ELSE Pattern END,
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Pattern) != 0 THEN SUBSTRING(Pattern, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Pattern), LEN(Pattern)) END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cross apply to simplify in-row calculations

```
select pattern
from pattern
cross apply (
    select leftLen = isnull(nullif(patindex('%[0-9]%', pattern),0) - 1, len(pattern))
          ,totalLen = len(pattern)  
    ) c
order by 
 case leftLen when totalLen then 2 else 1 end,
 left(Pattern, leftLen),
 cast(right(Pattern, totalLen-leftLen) as int)
```